# Finite element analysis, 1D

Tags: pde

I want the output to be values of C, at all range of `i` and `t` in the loops.

When I run it, I get `error in sym/subref, L_tilde, idx`.

I do not know what it means.

```
 syms C;

 alphaX=0.05;
 DiffCoef = 5*10^-5

 v = 0.1;
 L = 10; xZones = 100;

 dx = L/xZones;

 T = 150;
 u = 0.1;

 dt= 0.005;
  t = 150;
  D = DiffCoef + (alphaX * u);

 for i = 1:xZones
     for t = 1:xZones

         (C(i,t+dt) - C(i,t))/dt = -u(C(i+1,t +dt) - C(i,t+dt))/dx + D(C(i+1,t+dt) -  2*(C(i,t+dt) + C(i-1,t+dt)))/(dx)^2


     end
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is Matlab code, there are some problems:

1) you cannot assign two outputs so the statement

```
(C(i,t+dt) - C(i,t))/dt = ...
```

is illegal. Matlab expressions can only return one output (without using for example "deal"), so in your case you would have to rearrange your expression as maybe

```
C(i,t+dt) = ...
C(i,t) = ...
```

Moreover, as this seems it is a time difference formula typically anything *f(t+dt)* is the unknown (left hand side), and *f(t)* are the known values as previous time step (right hand side) so that

```
f(t+dt) = dt*old_rhs - f(t)
```

In your case you have prescribed _C(i,t_dt)_ which seems very unusual, so please check your equations.